# Conditional format two columns based on column values using DT package

Tags: r, dt

For example using the mtcars dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

dat <- mtcars
```

I want to color the background of the `dat$disp` column of the table based on the value in it. i.e. if the value is below 150 color green, if it is between 150 and 250 color orange, and above 250 color red.

I have tried using the help from another answer by doing:

```
dat <- mtcars
dat$colors <- with(dat, ifelse(disp<=150, "green", ifelse(disp>=250, "yellow"), "red"))

datatable(dat, 
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(visible = FALSE, targets = 12)
            )
          )
) %>% formatStyle("disp", valueColumns = "colors", backgroundColor = JS("value"))
```

But I think I am making this too complicated,  and this colors the cells red and yellow and doesn't follow the conditional formatting I would like.

I also want to use the same colors for the 'car name' column, so that they match the `disp` column.

I'm not very used to R and would really appreciate any guidance regarding this and the DT package, I am sure this is much simpler than I am making it out to be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be useful. The `colors` column is not necessary.
Attention the color: as you note if the value is
below 150 color green,
if it is between 150 and 250 color orange,
and above 250 color red.

```
dat <- dat %>% rownames_to_column(var = "car_name")
datatable(dat) %>% 
  formatStyle(
    c("disp", "car_name"),
    valueColumns = "disp",
    backgroundColor  = styleInterval(c(150, 250), c('green','orange', 'red'))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but it doesn't change the 'var' column to the same colors like the answer above.

Comment: Thank you, as this is neater I've marked it as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your question?

```
dat <- dat %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "car_name") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(colors = case_when(disp <= 150 ~ "green",
                            disp >= 250 ~ "yellow",
                            TRUE ~ "red"))

datatable(dat,
          options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
            visible = FALSE, targets = 12
          )))) %>% formatStyle(
            c("disp", "car_name"),
            valueColumns = "colors",
            backgroundColor = JS("value")
          )
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you @desmond. When I run it in Rmarkdown using RStudio I get the pop-up message: `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '10' for row 0, column 10. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4` - do you know why this is?

Comment: Ah - I think it is due to the number of columns, I have changed this to match my data `targets = 9` and it does not produce a pop-up.